# API to determine System Tray color

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

In Windows 10, most of the OS icons in the system tray (Audio, USB, Network...) are all white when on a dark background, but change to all black when on a white background. See below:

[image]

[image]

My question is, is there any way to programmatically detect what color the system tray background is so that I can respond by changing the color of my program's icon?

Comment: Based on your screenshots, looks like tray icons use `Transparent` background and (sometimes) `Inverse colour` foreground lines.

Comment: Thank you. I assume you are referring to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x40c0ykd.aspx ... I was not aware that this was even possible until you mentioned "Inverse colour". After searching a bit around that term, I found the linked article.